# How to write test that mocks the $route object in vue components

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a component that contains statement like `this.$route.fullPath`, how should I mock value of `fullPath`of `$route` object if I want to test that component?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I disagree with the top answer - you can mock `$route` without any issue.

On the other hand, installing vue-router multiple times on the base constructor *will* cause you problems. It adds `$route` and `$router` as read only properties. Which makes it impossible to overwrite them in future tests.

There are two ways to achieve this with [vue-test-utils](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils).

**Mocking vue-router with the [mocks option](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#mocks)**

```js
const $route = {
    fullPath: 'full/path'
}
const wrapper = mount(ComponentWithRouter, { 
  mocks: {
    $route
  } 
})

wrapper.vm.$route.fullPath // 'full/path'
```

You can also install Vue Router safely by using createLocalVue:

**Installing vue-router safely in tests with [createLocalVue](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#localvue)**

```js
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(VueRouter)
const routes = [
 {
   path: '/',
   component: Component
 }
]
const router = new VueRouter({
 routes
})
const wrapper = mount(ComponentWithRouter, { localVue, router })
expect(wrapper.vm.$route).to.be.an('object')
```

Comment: First approach doesn't work: `TypeError: Cannot set property $route of #<Vue$3> which has only a getter`.

Comment: Hi Daniel, this error is thrown because you've already installed VueRouter during your tests. Once you call Vue.use(VueRouter), $route and $router are added as read only properties. To be able to modify the $route or $router properties in a test, you must not install Vue Router on the global base constructor.

Comment: How do you mock $store using the first approach?

Comment: The same way, but pass $store instead of $route

Comment: `mocks: { $route }` gives read-only error with or without prior install of VueRouter.

Comment: I guarantee that you will have installed Vue Router somewhere in your code. Even importing a function from a file that calls Vue.use(VueRouter) will do it.

Comment: Worth noting that vue-cli drops a `Vue.use(Router)` in router/index.js, which is loaded into the global Vue.  If you have say, a `router.push` call in your component, it is importing that global read-only $router before the test (so it can't be mocked).

Comment: @JoeZoller, That's the problem I'm running into.  None of my tests load router, but it's being passed in from router/index.js.  So, when I want to test logic that calls $router.push I'm stuck as I am unable to mock or attach a spy.  Did you find a way around this?

Comment: Of note: this only happens when I use beforeEach.  I don't have an issue when I setup the wrapper and mocks inside the describe block.

Comment: @Nathan Agersea No real solution yet.  We ended up extracting the routing functionality to a different module for the more interesting code to test.

Comment: @Edd, this might be a basic question, but if a component uses $router.push(), is it still possible to mock $router? Or in that case is it better to implement an end-to-end test by installing VueRouter (using createLocalVue())?

Comment: @MatthewWhite you can mock a $route object with a push method and it will work fine!

Comment: `mocks: {$route}` doesn't work. $route is still empty when the component is created. No errors, it's just that the test fails. `router.push(path)` similarly doesn't work.

Comment: I'm doing this (setting a prop)  in a form pagesource: this.$route.fullPath and I tried the mock method - wrapper.vm.$route is populated in the test but it still bombs out complaining that $route is undefined in the component

Comment: For anyone using this now, mocks is now a subset of global:
https://test-utils.vuejs.org/migration/#mocks-and-stubs-are-now-in-global

Answer (score 42):

Best not mock `vue-router` but rather use it to render the component, that way you get a proper working router. Example:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import totest from 'src/components/totest'

describe('totest.vue', () => {
  it('should totest renders stuff', done => {
    Vue.use(VueRouter)
    const router = new VueRouter({routes: [
        {path: '/totest/:id', name: 'totest', component: totest},
        {path: '/wherever', name: 'another_component', component: {render: h => '-'}},
    ]})
    const vm = new Vue({
      el: document.createElement('div'),
      router: router,
      render: h => h('router-view')
    })
    router.push({name: 'totest', params: {id: 123}})
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
      console.log('html:', vm.$el)
      expect(vm.$el.querySelector('h2').textContent).to.equal('Fred Bloggs')
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

Things to note:

1. I'm using the runtime-only version of vue, hence `render: h => h('router-view')`.
2. I'm only testing the `totest` component, but others might be required if they're referenced by `totest` eg. `another_component` in this example.
3. You need `nextTick` for the HTML to have rendered before you can look at it/test it.

One of the problems is that most of the examples I found referred to the old version of `vue-router`, see [the migrations docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration-vue-router.html), eg. some examples use `router.go()` which now doesn't work.

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of time. However it could use some improvements: If you have multiple tests. you actually have to route to /whatever and then to /totest  if you want to reset the state. It would be better to find a way to destroy the router and build it again. When I built my router in each tests, I was getting strange behaviour (it seems like the router state was persisted, and routing to the same "page" did not trigger state changes)

Comment: [here](https://github.com/tutorcruncher/socket-frontend/blob/master/test/unit/specs/modal.js) is a full test setup which is working. That's probably the clearest approach to describing a full test setup.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this example and link to your project repo @SColvin. browsing your specs is helping me a ton, I hope to see and even create my own resources on how to test vue components in the future, it's something there definitely needs to be more of (or at least, more for people who havent had a lot of tdd experience). Thanks again for the great question + excellent answer.

Comment: No problem. I agree there aren't as many resources on the subject as I expected. But the most noticeable thing I found from starting with vue and writing unit tests with javascript was **quite how ugly javascript is**. There's a lot of polishing, and shaping and rolling in glitter but it's still fundamentally a shit. I've never appreciated python's elegance, simplicity and sheer communicativeness so much.

Comment: @SColvin link is dead :/ (The one on your comment)

Comment: [here](https://github.com/tutorcruncher/socket-frontend/blob/9140ca968ee7c42e498c25a40c391818c2726c5b/test/unit/specs/modal.js) is the test file as it was back in February. The tests are more complete now but perhaps less easy to get started with.

Comment: I disagree that you shouldn't mock Vue Router. See my answer — https://stackoverflow.com/a/44619365/4939630

Answer (score 7):

No answer was helping me out, So I dig into `vue-test-utils` documentation and found myself a working answer, so you need to import.

```
import { shallowMount,createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import router from '@/router.ts';
const localVue = createLocalVue();
```

We created a sample `vue` instance. While testing you need to use `shallowMount` so you can provide `vue` app instance and router.

```
describe('Components', () => {
  it('renders a comment form', () => {
    const COMMENTFORM = shallowMount(CommentForm,{
      localVue,
      router
    });
  })
})
```

You can easily pass router and to shallow mount and it does not gives you the error. If you want to pass store you use:

```
import { shallowMount,createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import router from '@/router.ts';
import store from '@/store.ts';
const localVue = createLocalVue();
```

And then pass store:

```
describe('Components', () => {
  it('renders a comment form', () => {
    const COMMENTFORM = shallowMount(CommentForm,{
      localVue,
      router,
      store
    });
  })
})
```

This solution solved the following errors:

- Cannot read property 'params' of undefined when using `this.$route.params.id`
- Unknown custom element `router-link`

✔

Comment: This solution doesn't actually mock the $route anywhere.

Comment: @mcv Do you have a solution for that?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest method i found is to use **localVue**

```js
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import ComponentName from '@/components/ComponentName.vue';
// Add store file if any getters is accessed
import store from '@/store/store';

describe('File name', () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();
  localVue.use(VueRouter);

  // Can also be replaced with route(router.js) file
  const routes = [
    {
      path: '/path',
      component: ComponentName,
      name: 'Route name'
    }
  ];

  const router = new VueRouter({ routes });

  // if needed
  router.push({
    name: 'Route name',
    params: {}
  });

  const wrapper = mount(ComponentName, {
    localVue,
    router,
    store
  });

  test('Method()', () => {
    wrapper.vm.methodName();

    expect(wrapper.vm.$route.path)
      .toEqual(routes[0].path);
  });
});
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 3):

Why are all answers so complicated? You can just do:

```
...
wrapper = mount(HappyComponent, {
  mocks: {
    $route: { fullPath: '' }
  },
})
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to specifically "mock" a router. Your application can set VueRouter in the global vue scope and you can still make it do what you want in your tests without issue.

Read the localVue usage with `VueRouter`: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#using-with-vue-router.

I am currently pulling in a complex router from our main app and am able to `jest.spyOn()` calls to `router.push()` as well as setting the path before the component is created running `shallowMount()` for some route handling in a `created()` hook.

**The Workaround**

// someVueComponent.vue

```
<template>
... something
</template>
<script>
...
data () {
  return {
    authenticated: false
  }
},
...
created () {
  if(!this.authenticated && this.$route.path !== '/'){
    this.$router.push('/')
  }
}
</script>
```

// someVueComponent.spec.js

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import SomeVueComponent from 'MyApp/components/someVueComponent'
import MyAppRouter from 'MyApp/router'
import MyAppCreateStore from 'MyApp/createStore'
import merge from 'lodash.merge'

function setVueUseValues (localVue) {
  localVue.use(Vuex)
  localVue.use(VueRouter)
  // other things here like custom directives, etc
}

beforeEach(() => {
  // reset your localVue reference before each test if you need something reset like a custom directive, etc
  localVue = createLocalVue()
  setVueUseValues(localVue)
})

let localVue = createLocalVue()
setVueUseValues(localVue)

test('my app does not react to path because its default is "/"', () => {
  const options = {
    localVue,
    router: MyAppRouter,
    store: MyAppCreateStore()  
  }  

  const routerPushSpy = jest.spyOn(options.router, 'push')
  const wrapper = shallowMount(SomeVueComponent, options)
  expect(routerPushSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)
})

test('my app reacts to path because its not "/" and were not authenticated', () => {
  const options = {
    localVue,
    router: MyAppRouter,
    store: MyAppCreateStore()  
  }

  const routerPushSpy = jest.spyOn(options.router, 'push')
  options.router.push('/nothomepath')
  expect(routerPushSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/nothomepath') // <- SomeVueComponent created hook will have $route === '/nothomepath' as well as fullPath

  const wrapper = shallowMount(SomeVueComponent, options)
  expect(routerPushSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/') // <- works
})
```

The above is done with the idea that I need the `$route` state changed before `SomeVueComponent.vue` is created/mounted. Assuming you can create the wrapper and want to test that the component `this.$router.push('/something')` based on some other state or action you can always spy on the `wrapper.vm` instance

```
let routerPushSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm.$router, 'push') // or before hooks, etc
```

As of this writing there seems to be an open defect which keeps the following from working because `vm.$route` will always be undefined, making the above the only option (that I know of) as there is no other way to "mock" the `$route` because installing VueRouter writes read only properties to `$route`.

From the vue-test-utils docs https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#mocking-route-and-router:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'

const $route = {
  path: '/some/path'
}

const wrapper = shallowMount(Component, {
  mocks: {
    $route
  }
})

wrapper.vm.$route.path // /some/path
```

If your interested here is the github link to a reproduction of the issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/1136

Answer (score 1):

All kudos to @SColvin for his answer; helped find an answer in my scenario wherein I had a component with a router-link that was throwing a

```
ERROR: '[Vue warn]: Error in render function: (found in <RouterLink>)'
```

during unit test because Vue hadn't been supplied with a router. Using @SColvin answer to rewrite the test originally supplied by vue-cli from

```
describe('Hello.vue', () =>
{
  it('should render correct contents', () =>
  {
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(Hello);
    const vm = new Constructor().$mount();
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('.hello h1').textContent)
      .to.equal('Welcome to Your Vue.js App');
  });
```

to

```
describe('Hello.vue', () =>
{
  it('should render correct contents', () =>
  {
    Vue.use(VueRouter);
    const router = new VueRouter({
      routes: [
        { path: '/', name: 'Hello', component: Hello },
      ],
    });
    const vm = new Vue({
      el: document.createElement('div'),
      /* eslint-disable object-shorthand */
      router: router,
      render: h => h('router-view'),
    });
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('.hello h1').textContent)
      .to.equal('Welcome to Your Vue.js App');
  });
});
```

Not needing to pass parameters in to the view I could simplify the component as the default render, no need to push and no need to wait nextTick. HTH someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the great answer from @SColvin, here's an example of this working using [Avoriaz](https://eddyerburgh.gitbooks.io/avoriaz/):

```
import { mount } from 'avoriaz'
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import router from '@/router'
import HappyComponent from '@/components/HappyComponent'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

describe('HappyComponent.vue', () => {
  it('renders router links', () => {
    wrapper = mount(HappyComponent, {router})
    // Write your test
  })
})
```

I believe this should work with [vue-test-utils](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/), too.

Comment: What are these `@/` before the routes about?

Comment: @webdevguy It's a common [Webpack resolve alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) used by the Vue team as a shortcut to the `src` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example using vue-test-utils, where I'm mocking both router and store.

```
import ArticleDetails from '@/components/ArticleDetails'
import { mount } from 'vue-test-utils'
import router from '@/router'

describe('ArticleDetails.vue', () => {
  it('should display post details', () => {
    const POST_MESSAGE = 'Header of our content!'

    const EXAMPLE_POST = {
      title: 'Title',
      date: '6 May 2016',
      content: `# ${POST_MESSAGE}`
    }

    const wrapper = mount(ArticleDetails, {
      router,

      mocks: {
        $store: {
          getters: {
            getPostById () {
              return EXAMPLE_POST
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })

    expect(wrapper.vm.$el.querySelector('h1.post-title').textContent.trim()).to.equal(EXAMPLE_POST.title)
    expect(wrapper.vm.$el.querySelector('time').textContent.trim()).to.equal(EXAMPLE_POST.date)
    expect(wrapper.vm.$el.querySelector('.post-content').innerHTML.trim()).to.equal(
      `<h1>${POST_MESSAGE}</h1>`
    )
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've been doing as per [this article](https://eddyerburgh.me/stub-$route-in-vue-unit-tests):

```
it('renders $router.name', () => {
    const scopedVue = Vue.extend();

    const mockRoute = {
        name: 'abc'
    };

    scopedVue.prototype.$route = mockRoute;

    const Constructor = scopedVue.extend(Component);
    const vm = new Constructor().$mount();
    expect(vm.$el.textContent).to.equal('abc');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock to **vm.$router** by setting **vm._routerRoot._router**

For example

```
var Constructor      = Vue.extend(Your_Component)
var vm               = new Constructor().$mount()
var your_mock_router = {hello:'there'}

vm.$router             = your_mock_router //An error 'setting a property that has only a getter'
vm._routerRoot._router = your_mock_router //Wow, it works!
```

You can double check their source code here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/dist/vue-router.js#L558

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way i've found is to mock the $route.

```
it('renders $router.name', () => {
  const $route = {
    name: 'test name - avoriaz'
  }


 const wrapper = shallow(Component, {
    mocks: {
      $route
    }
  })
  expect(wrapper.text()).to.equal($route.name)
})
```